# Device node increment of storage devices

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver, usb-drive

I am getting a issue of device node getting incremented for storage device when reconnected.

For eg. when device is connected first time it gets a node /dev/sda but when I reconnect device it                                                              changes to /dev/sdb, repeating this activity increments the device node to sdc, sdd, sde and so on..

I looked for the refcount of the kobject it is getting changed from 3 to 2 when device is disconnected.

I also found that this refcount is not getting changed because udevd is holding /dev/sda (I found this using ***lsof*** command).

So currently I'm stuck whether is this a user level problem or kernel level problem.

Comment: Usually, this kind of stuff happens when you re-insert the storage device without proper unmounting in the previous insertion.

Comment: Device is being unmounted properly by the manager. 
Also the issue is resolved. There was some problem with udev.
Thanks for your help.